# If statement evaluates to false but still branches as if it was true

Tags: c#, debugging, exception

I am quite stumped. In an async method, I have a few initial guard statements, that throw exceptions if specific conditions are met.

One of them is the following:

```
var txPagesCount = _transactionPages.Count;
if (txPagesCount == 0)
    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Cannot commit transaction {0}. It is empty.", _txId));
```

This is supposed to ensure there are pages in the `_transactionPages` dictionary and throw if there are none.

This is what happens when I run it (release and debug build, debugger attached):

[image: Number of pages is 3]

So the number of pages in the dictionary is 3.

[image: if statement evaluates to false]

And so, as expected, the if statement comparing 3 to 0 evaluates to false.

But then, when stepping further:

[image: Steps into the branch]

It steps into the branch as if the if statement evaluated to true, and throws the exception.

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

When I do this:

```
private static readonly object _globalLock = new object();

public async Task<Checkpoint> CommitAsync(PageNumber dataRoot, PageNumber firstUnusedPage)
{
    lock (_globalLock)
    {
        if (IsCompleted)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Cannot commit completed transaction {0}", _txId));
        var txPagesCount = _transactionPages.Count;
        if (txPagesCount == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Cannot commit transaction {0}. It is empty.", _txId));
    }
```

the if statement does not branch to throw the exception. This is the case for both debug and release build. Is something messing up the call stack? Also, if instead of the lock I add `System.Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier();` after the `if` statement, it will not go into the branch.

**UPDATE 2**

The mystery becomes a bit larger. It is almost as if c++ scoping rules are used :D The code below (**in debug build**) will show the expected behavior: not go into the branch and not throw. In **release build**, it will go into the branch and throw just as before.

```
private static readonly object _globalLock = new object();

public async Task<Checkpoint> CommitAsync(PageNumber dataRoot, PageNumber firstUnusedPage)
{
    //lock (_globalLock)
    {
        if (IsCompleted)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Cannot commit completed transaction {0}", _txId));
        var txPagesCount = _transactionPages.Count;
        if (txPagesCount == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Cannot commit transaction {0}. It is empty.", _txId));
    }
```

If I comment out the "scoping braces" it will go into the branch and throw the exception (as in my original images).

**FINAL? UPDATE**

Well that sucks. I made a few changes to unrelated areas of code and now I am no longer able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Clean/rebuild solution

Comment: Is it possible your debugging symbols are out of date?

Comment: Are you only calling it once?  It looks like you might have a couple calls running here.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I had already done that. Makes no difference.

Comment: The 3 is the correct number. This is the first call to this method.

Comment: Is it possible that another thread is mutating `txPagesCount` while this is going on?  If the value change after you inspect it with the debugger, that could result in this behavior.

Comment: That is why I made it a local variable on the stack, so no there is nothing going on that could mutate it other than a random write to memory, but no other threads are running. Note I also checked debug build with the same result.

Comment: The debug build would generally be more informative. Worse case, you need to look at the assembly to see what it generates.

Comment: @Servy, the `txPagesCount` can't be mutated by another thread.

Comment: Sometimes it is need to manually remove all `obj` and `bin` subfolders to clean solution.

Comment: When debugging with the release build, the line it indicates it's on doesn't always make perfect sense. When you let the code execute, does it actually throw or not?

Comment: You say this is the _first_ call to this method but is it the _only_ call to this method?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan manually removed directories & rebuilt. Same result. And Tim, yes it actually throws (which is why I started debugging this).

Comment: Also, fwiw, the shared state (`_txId` & `_transactionPages`) are the likely cause of your headaches.  Can you rewrite this in such a way that those values are passed into this method rather than shared as class variables?

Comment: @AustinSalonen the method will be called multiple times, but only once for each instance of the class it is a part of (which is why the "IsCompleted" guard is there).

Comment: @AustinSalonen could you please explain how the presence of private instance variables `_txId` and `_transactionPages` that are also not modified during this call could lead to a local stack variable `txPagesCount` with the value 3 being changed or have an effect on the if statement or branching behavior?

Comment: Without seeing the full source, no.  But if those values can be mutated by any other method, they are suspect.  As for the branching issue, if you are debugging multiple calls, the debugger could have stepped into the other task and you might be assuming you're in a different one, which is why I asked if you were debugging only one call.

Comment: @AustinSalonen yes, but in that case, those calls should also have hit the breakpoint at line 106, and they don't. The breakpoint is hit only once.

Comment: Just to be clear the exception is actually thrown? You aren't just looking at what lines are highlighted?

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, the exception is actually thrown.

Comment: It is maybe the case when optimization arise and `var txPagesCount = _transactionPages.Count; if (txPagesCount == 0)` changed by `if (_transactionPages.Count== 0)`. Then `_transactionPages` changed by another thread.

Comment: What type is `_transactionPages`? Are you sure `_transactionPages.Count` returns an `int`?

Comment: There is no way. I am reasonably sure your code is lining up with out of date debug symbols and it looks like your condition is passing when it is not. Create another project and migrate just the text files, compile, and run. Also be wary of where any .dlls are being linked from.

Comment: as @AdiLester pointed out if _transactionPages is a null then _transactionPages.Count will not be a int.

Comment: @N4TKD The `_transactionPages` instance variable is a private read-only generic dictionary. Its `Count` property is an integer.

Comment: @nsfyn55 then how come the exception is actually thrown?

Comment: @Alex I (and a couple others it seems from comments) have the distinct feeling you're watching more than one thread execute at the same time and not realizing what is happening in which thread...  C# IDE debugger ain't great for this.  (I mean it could just be "dirty makefiles" but)

Comment: @ebyrob That is what I was thinking too at first. But in that case, one of those threads should also have hit the breakpoint at line 106 and that did not happen. I agree though that debugging threaded code is not easy and not generally the preferred way of finding out what is happening, but I was simply flabbergasted by what I observed when I did.

Comment: @Alex In general, unless you have things absolutely under control, never make any assumptions about the C# IDE when debugging threads.  "could" and "could not" are often just seemingly logical traps here.  (debugging threaded code is the *only* way, I just don't recommend the IDE for it)

Comment: @Alex if _transactionPages is a null then _transactionPages.Count is a null and using var it would end up being object null not 0.

Comment: @N4TKD it is a *readonly* private instance member variable initialized as `_transactionPages = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, Tuple<PageBlock, StoragePage>>();` in the constructor. Also, as you can see in the screenshot, the value of the local `txPagesCount` variable was 3, not null.

Comment: @Alex yes I saw the 3 after I commented.

Comment: @Alex what happens if you use int and not var.

Comment: @N4TKD I tried that before and it did not change anything. B.t.w. see my last update. I was stupid enough to make some more changes to unrelated parts of the code and am currently unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Alex that can just make you crazy :)

Comment: @Alex I think the code was lining up serendipitously. I have had this exact same problem in the past. Debug symbols have just a little info including the source line number the instruction is associated with. If the source and the symbols get out of sync you get all kinds of apparently non-deterministic behavior. Its easy to spot when the debugger drops you on a blank line or a comment, but not so much when you just invert a conditional and all the other code stays at the same line position.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, asynchronous debugging.

I only ever found one way to do this effectively.  Use tracing (hopefully something decent, maybe log4net).  Make sure to output timestamp and threadId on every single line.  (also support synchronization of output per call to trace library for when you need it which doesn't have to be on all the time)

That's it really.

Note: Simply writing to a file or stdout works for a first blush, but if you start using it more, get a library.